# LXC & OverlayFS

Tags: webserver, lxc, lxd, overlayfs

**Goal** - To configure/install a webapp on Host & make sure its accessible through an lxc container.

**Why** - To isolate the host yet provide access to the web app and ssh access to our clients.

**Question** - Should I configure the LXC with overlayFS and mount the webapp config files or simply implement port forwarding skipping overlayFS implementation?

Comment: Neither "goal" nor "why" say anything about why you're using overlayfs.

Comment: I need to isolate the host (where the web app is installed) from any sort of modification by the clients yet provide them ssh access. All modifications on the lxc would be made on the upper layer - thus helping me isolate both the workspaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to fully setup the webapp in a LXD container, and give them access to this LXD container over SSH. In this way, your host will not be exposed at all, and what happens in this webapp container, stays in the webapp container. If you have multiple customers on the same server, you can put each customer in their own container. Then, set up a reverse proxy (such as HAProxy) to direct each incoming connection to the corresponding container. See, for example, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-web-sites-with-nginx-and-haproxy-using-lxd-on-ubuntu-16-04 
You can also setup HAProxy as a TLS Termination proxy, meaning that all websites will be `https` and the certificates will be managed at a single location in HAProxy.

If you really what to do what you have described in the question, here is how to do it:
1. You do no mess with the overlayFS, because it does not work in that way in LXC/LXD. 
2. You can bind-mount (https://blog.ubuntu.com/2016/12/08/mounting-your-home-directory-in-lxd) the webapp directory from the host to make it appear in a container. Inside the container they will be able to see the subdirectory that has the webapp files. Still, they could easily modify a .php file and expose your host in scary ways. Therefore, go for the first option.

Also, see https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/comparing-lxd-vs-lxc/24 for the difference between LXC and LXD.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance Simos! At present I have configured the LXC container in this manner - check answer section

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a 'Master' LXC container & a snapshot-copy of the Master. 
The snapshot-copy uses an OverlayFS; the rootfs of the original (Master) and the rootfs of the snapshot-copy are stored on separate locations.

Changes are stored in delta0, within the snapshot-copy. This allows for any changes to be stored separately. So customers using the webapp or the ssh service would be able to make changes on the overlay and not the underlay!

The web app is set up on Master and runs within the snapshot-copy. Works perfectly!

Comment: Can you write a guide on this? A simple *a la helloworld*  guide should be fine.

Comment: Sure! I am currently working (and learning) on configuring the snapshot-copy in a separate mounted directory. (its an added requirement). For this I am looking into LXD since it supports multiple storage pools. Once done I will definitely list all the commands/steps here

Comment: @Simos - Would I be able to configure LXC containers to run from 2 different locations? for instance - can I configure the master in /var/lib/lxc/master and the snapshot under /newdev/lxc/snapshot-copy ?

Comment: I am not familiar with LXC to give a useful answer. You will most likely get a better answer if you ask at https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/